# Add columns to pandas dataframe containing max of each row, AND corresponding column name

Tags: python, pandas

**My system**

Windows 7, 64 bit

python 3.5.1

**The challenge**

I've got a pandas dataframe, and I would like to know the **maximum value for each row**, and append that info as a new column. I would also like to know the name of the column where the maximum value is located. And I would like to add another column to the existing dataframe containing the name of the column where the max value can be found.

A similar question has been asked and answered for R in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010345/subset-data-frame-in-order-to-contain-max-value-of-each-row-and-the-column-name).

**Reproducible example**

```
In[1]:
# Make pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,0,1,3], 'b':[0,0,1,0,1], 'c':[0,0,0,0,0]})

# Calculate max 
my_series = df.max(numeric_only=True, axis = 1)
my_series.name = "maxval"

# Include maxval in df
df = df.join(my_series)
df        

Out[1]:
    a  b  c  maxval
0   1  0  0  1
1   0  0  0  0
2   0  1  0  1
3   1  0  0  1
4   3  1  0  3
```

So far so good. Now for the **add another column to the existing dataframe containing the name of the column** part:

```
In[2]:
?
?
?


# This is what I'd like to accomplish:
Out[2]:
        a  b  c  maxval maxcol
    0   1  0  0  1      a
    1   0  0  0  0      a,b,c       
    2   0  1  0  1      b
    3   1  0  0  1      a
    4   3  1  0  3      a
```

Notice that I'd like to return all column names if multiple columns contain the same maximum value. Also please notice that the column **maxval** is not included in **maxcol** since that would not make much sense. Thanks in advance if anyone out there finds this interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the df against `maxval` using `eq` with `axis=0`, then use `apply` with a `lambda` to produce a boolean mask to mask the columns and `join` them:

```
In [183]:
df['maxcol'] = df.ix[:,:'c'].eq(df['maxval'], axis=0).apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[:3][x==x.max()]),axis=1)
df

Out[183]:
   a  b  c  maxval maxcol
0  1  0  0       1      a
1  0  0  0       0  a,b,c
2  0  1  0       1      b
3  1  0  0       1      a
4  3  1  0       3      a
```