# How to pass a function as a parameter to another function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas

I'm doing a bunch of operations on pandas dataframes. For example finding **max**, **min** and **average** inside columns and [return the column names in a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223461/add-columns-to-pandas-dataframe-containing-max-of-each-row-and-corresponding-co). Now I'm trying to wrap these things into a function, and use `max()` and/or `min()` as arguments in this function.

Below is a snippet that describes what I'm trying to do in a very simplified way. In its current state it also returns a description of the desired output. The snippet does not have the desired functionality and flexibility though.

#### The setup:

```
# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_A':[1,20,6,1,3]})

def findValue(function, df, colname):

    print(function) # just a placeholder
    df[colname] = df.max()[0]

    return df

df2 = findValue(function='max', df=df, colname='col_B')
print(df)
```

#### Output 1:

```
   col_A  col_B
0      1     20
1     20     20
2      6     20
3      1     20
4      3     20
```

#### A naive attempt:

```
# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_A':[1,20,6,1,3]})

# The function I would like to use in another function is max()

# My function 
def findValue(function, df, colname):
    df[colname] = df.function()[0]

    return df

df2 = findValue(function=max(), df=df , colname='col_B')
print(df)
```

#### Output 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-85964ff29e69>", line 1, in <module>
    df2 = findValue(function=max(), df=df , colname='col_B')

TypeError: max expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

How can I change the above snippet so that I can change `function = max()` to `function = min()` or any other function in the arguments of `findValue()`? Or even define a list of functions to be used in a similar manner?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Not that this is _exactly_ what you are looking for, but are you aware of the `describe()` method? Will return a DataFrame of max, min, mean, std. dev., count for each col in the DataFrame (or a Series of these values, if run on a Series). [docs] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)

Comment: If you have a look at the link in the question, you'll see that I'm going to use what I was looking for as part of a bigger function where I'm not only using the measures covered by `describe()`. But it will certainly be useful, so thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very, very close. You pretty much just need to remove the parens when passing in the function. Here's a simplified example that loops over a list of function names, and appears to do what you want:

```
def findValue(func, x, y):
    return func(x, y)

for calc in (max, min):
    result = findValue(func=calc, x=1, y=10)
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
10
1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Does this technique have a name? I'm asking because I don't think 'change functions within a python function' is the best way to describe what we're doing here. Also, I did not have much success googling this.

Comment: @vestland Essentially, you're passing a function as a parameter to another function.