# Pandas: How to assign sum() or mean() to df.groupby inside a function?

Tags: python, function, pandas

I'd like to wrap `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()` in a function so that I can assign `sum()`, `mean()` or `count()` as arguments in that function. I've asked a similar question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700734/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-to-another-function), but I don't think I can use the same technique in this particular case.

**Here is a snippet with reproducible input:**

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframe with 1 or zero
# 100 rows and 4 columns
# Indexed by dates
np.random.seed(12345678)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2017, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=100).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df.head(10))
```

Which gives:

[image]

With this we can do:

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()
print(df2)
```

And get:

[image]

Or we can do:

```
df3 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()
print(df3)
```

And get:

[image]

**Here's part of the procedure wrapped into a function:**

```
# My function
def function1(df):
    df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()
    return df

# Function1 call
df4 = function1(df = df)
print(df4)
```

And that works just fine:

[image]

**The problem occurs when I try to add `sum()` or `mean()` as an argument in Function2, like this:**

```
# My function with sum() as an argument
def function2(df, fun):
    df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).fun
    return df
```

My first attempt raises a TypeError:

```
# Function2 test 1
df5 = function2(df = df, fun = sum())
```

[image]

My second attempt raises an attribute error:

```
# Function2 test 2
df6 = function2(df = df, fun = 'sum()')
```

[image]

Is it possible to make a few adjustments to this setup to get it working? (I tried another version with 'M' as an argument for freq, and that worked just fine). Or is this just not the way these things are done?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Here is the whole mess for an easy copy&paste:

```
#%%

# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframe with 1 or zero
# 100 rows across 4 columns
# Indexed by dates
np.random.seed(12345678)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2017, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=100).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df.head(10))

# Calculate sum per month
df2 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()
print(df2)

# Or calculate average per month
df3 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()
print(df3)

# My function
def function1(df):
    df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()
    return df

# Function1 test
df4 = function1(df = df)
print(df4)
# So far so good
#%%
# My function with sum() as argument
def function2(df, fun):
    print(fun)
    df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).fun
    return df

# Function2 test 1
# df5 = function2(df = df, fun = sum())

# Function2 test 2
# df6 = function2(df = df, fun = 'sum()')

# Function2 test 3
# df7 = function2(df = df, fun = sum)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `apply`

```
def function2(df, fun):
    return df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).apply(fun)
```

Just make sure `fun` is a callable that takes a `pd.DataFrame`

---

However, you should probably use `agg`.  If `fun` reduces columns to a scalar similar to `sum` or `mean`, then this should work.  Something to consider.

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).agg(['sum', 'mean', fun])
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent suggestion! I've got a quick follow-up question if you don't mind. This way, sum works fine, but mean does not. However np.mean does work. Neither count nor np.count works. Any views on that?

Comment: @vestland if you are using my suggestion to use apply, fun needs to be a function. 'mean' is a string. np.mean is a function. The function also has to take a dataframe as the first argument and return something that pandas can deal with. np.mean takes a dataframe, acts on the values and returns the mean of the whole array. I'm not sure what np.count does. 'count' is a string and won't work. You'd be better off posting a new question presenting more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I ended up using agg() and that works really well. Thank you for the additional details!

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment of @BlackJack, here is a simpler implementation that uses `getattr(gb, foo)` to get the method `foo` on the `gb` groupby object.  If such a method does not exist, it raises an AttributeError.  Depending on use, you may wish to control which functions you can pass as arguments to the `foo` parameter (see second example below).

```
def function(df, foo):
    gb = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
    try:
        foo = getattr(gb, foo)
    except AttributeError:
        raise('{} cannot be performed on this object'.format(foo))
    return foo()
```

Here is an alternative approach. This uses `eval` which is evil because of security concerns.  *However*, it first ensures that `foo` is a known function type that can safely be applied to either a 
`pd.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy` or  `pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object.

```
def function2(df, foo):
    safe_functions = ('sum', 'mean', 'count')
    if foo not in safe_functions:
        raise ValueError('foo is not safe')
    gb = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
    if not isinstance(gb, (pd.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy, pd.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy)):
        raise ValueError('Unexpected groupby result')
    return eval('gb.{}()'.format(foo))

>>> function(df, 'sum')
             A   B   C   D
dates                     
2017-01-31  18  15  14  14
2017-02-28  15  15  12  17
2017-03-31  18  17  16  17
2017-04-30   8   3   3   7
```

Comment: `eval()` isn't an excellent suggestion, especially if it is simple to solve without: `return getattr(gb, foo)()`. It is even shorter.